# Changing specific elements of a list with different values

Tags: f#

I am trying to write a function that takes in a tuple of int and an int list and a max value, and uses this to update the instances of 1 in the tuple - I know how to use List.map to go through and update each instance but can't think how to go through and replace the 1st or last instance in a list with different values

```
let rower (t:int * int list) (size: int) : int list = 
    let (count, row) = t

    let first = count + 1
    let last = (size * size) - count

    let ret = 
        row 
        |> List.map (* how do I change the first instance of 1? *)
        |> List.map (* how do I change the last instance of 1? *)

    printfn "%A first %d last %d" t first last

    row

let ``the first test`` = 
    let expected = [0; 2; 0; 8; 0]
    let actual = rower (1, [0; 1; 0; 1; 0]) 3
    expected = actual 

printfn "%b" ``the first test``
```

Comment: I'd probably approach this by first finding the indices of the first and last occurrence with `List.findIndex` (or `List.tryFindIndex` if it isn't guaranteed that the value will be present). Then use `List.mapi` and check the indices of the numbers: if they're the indices you're going to change, change them, otherwise pass the old value through unchanged. (BTW, to find the last index of something, try `List.rev` followed by `List.tryFindIndex`).

Comment: That's exactly it! I'll post an answer below

Comment: I forgot about findIndexBack; that's better than List.rev followed by List.tryFindIndex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rmunn explained exactly how to do it - see below:

```
let rower (t:int* int list) (size: int) : int list = 
    let (count, row) = t

    let first = count + 1
    let last = (size * size) - count

    let i = row |> List.findIndex (fun x -> x = 1)
    let j = row |> List.findIndexBack (fun x -> x = 1)

    row 
    |> List.mapi (fun idx x -> 
        if idx = i then first 
        elif idx = j then last
        else x)

let ``the first test`` = 
    let expected = [0; 2; 0; 8; 0]
    let actual = rower (1, [0; 1; 0; 1; 0]) 3
    expected = actual 

printfn "%b" ``the first test``
```